# How to split a dataframe array into columns using Python in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm new to databricks and I'm using databricks with Python, I have created a schema of json file, and as a result dataframe (display(result)) it gives this result :

```
docs
-------
 [

{

  "id": 1,

  "name": "product 1",

  "brand": "new 1",

  "val": [

    {

      "value": "test 1"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 2"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 3"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 1"

    }

  ]

},

{

  "id": 2,

  "name": "product 2",

  "brand": "new 2",

  "val": [

    {

      "value": "test 1"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 2"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 3"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 1"

    }

  ]

},

{

  "id": 3,

  "name": "product 3",

  "brand": "new 3",

  "val": [

    {

      "value": "test 1"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 2"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 3"

    },

    {

      "value": "test 1"

    }

  ]

}

]
```

and what I'm looking for is how to put these data in seperate columns like :

```
id      name           brand     val
```

---

```
 1.     product 1       new 1.   [{"value":"test 1"},...]
 2.     product 2.      ....      ....
```

and so on..
is there a way to do that with python in databricks please ?

Comment: Can you share  the schema of `result` dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `result` dataframe has the following schema

```
root
 |-- docs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

You can use the `explode` to break `arrays` into rows and flatten the contained `struct` into columns.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = """{"docs": [{'id': 1,
  'name': 'product 1',
  'brand': 'new 1',
  'val': [{'value': 'test 1'},
   {'value': 'test 2'},
   {'value': 'test 3'},
   {'value': 'test 1'}]},
 {'id': 2,
  'name': 'product 2',
  'brand': 'new 2',
  'val': [{'value': 'test 1'},
   {'value': 'test 2'},
   {'value': 'test 3'},
   {'value': 'test 1'}]},
 {'id': 3,
  'name': 'product 3',
  'brand': 'new 3',
  'val': [{'value': 'test 1'},
   {'value': 'test 2'},
   {'value': 'test 3'},
   {'value': 'test 1'}]}]}"""

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([data, ])
df = spark.read.option("enforceSchema", "true").json(rdd, "docs ARRAY<STRUCT<id: INT, name STRING, brand: STRING, val: ARRAY<STRUCT<value: STRING>>>>")

df.select(F.explode("docs").alias("doc")).select("doc.*").show(truncate=False)
```

### Output

```
+---+---------+-----+----------------------------------------+
|id |name     |brand|val                                     |
+---+---------+-----+----------------------------------------+
|1  |product 1|new 1|[{test 1}, {test 2}, {test 3}, {test 1}]|
|2  |product 2|new 2|[{test 1}, {test 2}, {test 3}, {test 1}]|
|3  |product 3|new 3|[{test 1}, {test 2}, {test 3}, {test 1}]|
+---+---------+-----+----------------------------------------+
```